# Listview with the given xml model

Tags: listview, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, datamodel

Hi I'm new to Blackberry 10 cascades development.

I want to create a list with the below data model(which is placed in assests folder).

**Categories.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <MasterData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <CategoryList>
    <Category>
       <CategoryId>12</CategoryId>
       <CategoryNameEn>Banks &amp; Investments</CategoryNameEn>
       <CategoryImageName>banks.png</CategoryImageName>
       <DisplayOrder>1</DisplayOrder>
    </Category>
    <Category>
       <CategoryId>15</CategoryId>
       <CategoryNameEn>Car Rental</CategoryNameEn>
       <CategoryImageName>cars.png</CategoryImageName>
       <DisplayOrder>2</DisplayOrder>
    </Category>
    <Category>
       <CategoryId>19</CategoryId>
       <CategoryNameEn>Services</CategoryNameEn>
       <CategoryImageName>services.png</CategoryImageName>
       <DisplayOrder>3</DisplayOrder>
    </Category>
    <Category>
       <CategoryId>18</CategoryId>
       <CategoryNameEn>Real Estate &amp; Constructions</CategoryNameEn>
       <CategoryImageName>construction.png</CategoryImageName>
       <DisplayOrder>5</DisplayOrder>
    </Category>
    <Category>
       <CategoryId>2</CategoryId>
       <CategoryNameEn>Hotels &amp; Apartments</CategoryNameEn>
       <CategoryImageName>hotels.png</CategoryImageName>
      <DisplayOrder>7</DisplayOrder>
    </Category>
 </CategoryList>
```

I want to display the only **CategoryNameEn** as the list item.

In the **main.qml** i have given like this.

```
    // Create a ListView that uses an XML data model
ListView {
    dataModel: XmlDataModel {
        source: "asset:///categories.xml"
    }
    // The ListItemComponent defines how "listItem" items should appear. 
    listItemComponents: [
        ListItemComponent {
            type: "Category" //setting the node name
            Container {
                preferredWidth: 748
                preferredHeight: 50
                background: Color.Blue

                layout: StackLayout {
                    orientation: LayoutOrientation.LeftToRight
                }

                Label {
                    text: ListItemData.CategoryNameEn //setting the node 
                    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                    // Apply a text style to create a title-sized font
                    // with normal weight
                    textStyle {
                        base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.TitleText
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.Normal
                    }
                }
                Container {
                    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                    preferredWidth: 50
                    preferredHeight: 50
                    //background: Color.Blue

                    layout: StackLayout {
                        orientation: LayoutOrientation.RightToLeft
                    }
                    // Arrow image
                    ImageView {
                        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                        translationX: 0
                        translationY: 0
                        imageSource: "asset:///images/arrow.png"
                        rightMargin: 10
                    }
                } // end of inner Container
            }//end of outer container
         } // end of ListItemComponent
    ]//end of listItemComponents
}//end of ListView
```

**The output should be like the below image.**

[image]

But the list is empty. The **CategoryNameEn** is not binding to the list. 
I don't know what is the wrong in my code. Please solve my issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind the data to the list item of list view in cascades](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963643/how-to-bind-the-data-to-the-list-item-of-list-view-in-cascades)

Comment: hi Kernald would you please help me to figure out what is the wrong in my code. Could you please use the above xml and listview and create simple project for figure out the error. Thanks

Comment: I answered on your first question.

Comment: And I suggest your look at console. You get error immediately...

Answer (score 0):

Here, I didn't fix your XML, just a small example how to fix it. XML:

```
 <model>
    <item CategoryNameEn="Banks &amp; Investments" CategoryId="12"  CategoryImageName="banks.png" DisplayOrder="1"/>
    <item CategoryNameEn="Banks &amp; Investments2" CategoryId="33"  CategoryImageName="banks2.png" DisplayOrder="2" />    
 </model>
```

QML:

```
ListView {
    dataModel: XmlDataModel {

        source: "asset:///categories.xml"
    }
    // The ListItemComponent defines how "listItem" items should appear.
    listItemComponents: [
        ListItemComponent {
            type: "item" //setting the node name
            Container {
                preferredWidth: 748
                preferredHeight: 50
                background: Color.Blue

                layout: StackLayout {
                    orientation: LayoutOrientation.LeftToRight
                }

                Label {
                    text: ListItemData.CategoryNameEn //setting the node
                    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                    // Apply a text style to create a title-sized font
                    // with normal weight
                    textStyle {
                        base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.TitleText
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.Normal
                    }
                }
                Container {
                    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                    preferredWidth: 50
                    preferredHeight: 50
                    //background: Color.Blue

                    layout: StackLayout {
                        orientation: LayoutOrientation.RightToLeft
                    }
                    // Arrow image
                    ImageView {
                        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                        translationX: 0
                        translationY: 0
                        imageSource: "asset:///images/arrow.png"
                        rightMargin: 10
                    }
                } // end of inner Container
            } //end of outer container
        } // end of ListItemComponent
    ] //end of listItemComponents
}    //end of ListView
```

Comment: I've changed the model(categories.xml) like above. But now also I'm not getting the output.

Comment: I'm getting this message on the console.  "Aug 08 05:28:13.331    com.example.STCDirectory.testDev_TCDirectorye0359adc.253837444    default    9000    NOTICE      XmlDataModel: Cannot set 'asset:///models/categories.xml' as source, currently only file paths are supported."

Comment: I've removed the asset:/// from the path, then items are displaying but the CategoryIds are displaying instead of categoryNameEn.

Comment: It says text: `ListItemData.CategoryNameEn`, so that should be shown. You must have done something with your XML, check that it is correct naming